# Why my form is skipping every other item

Tags: forms

I'm doing a project for a class, basically trying to do a survey to match people with a dorm based on their desired lifestyle. I copied the syntax for the form and some of them pop up correctly-the question appears with a drop down menu, but then the questions "how often do you plan on going to red lion" and "how do you plan on eating most of your meals" dont show up, and the options that should be in the drop down menu appear as text on the page, not as a drop down menu. any ideas? Heres the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
    <title> Find the right dorm for you </title>

    <h1>Find out what dorm fits your lifestyle!</h1>

</head>
<body>
    <p> Please fill out a few quesitons so we can help you figure out which dorm    is best for you. </p>

<form method="get" action="slutsky1-results.php">

    I enjoy (check all that apply):<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="act1" value="8">Working Out<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="act2" value="3">Bowling<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="act3" value="3">Live Music<br>     
    <input type="checkbox" name="act4" value="5">Shopping<br>   
    <input type="checkbox" name="act5" value="7">Food<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="act6" value="9">Bars <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="act7" value="9">Frat Parties <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="act8" value="8">Sports <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="act9" value="3">Library <br>


    Is being close to the quad important to you?:
    <select name= "Quad">
    <option value="1">Not important</option>
    <option value="3">Kind of important</option>
    <option value="6">Very Important</option>
    <option value="3">Only thing that matters</option> <br>

    How often do you plan on going to Red Lion?:
    <select name= "Lion">
    <option value="1">Never</option>
    <option value="5">Sometimes</option>
    <option value="10">Over 3 times a week</option> <br>

    Would you rather go to the ARC or CRCE?:
    <select name= "Gym">
    <option value="10">Arc</option>
    <option value="1">CRCE</option>
    <br>

    How do you plan on eating most of your meals?:
    <select name= "Gym">
    <option value="5">Ordering delivery</option>
    <option value="8">Walking To Green St.</option>
    <option value="5">Making my own food</option>
    <br>

    Private or Public dorm?:
    <select name= "Gym">
    <option value="10">Private</option>
    <option value="5">Public</option>
    <br>



    <input type="submit" value="get my results!">

    </form>



    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't closing your select tags. So the browser is trying to guess what you are trying to accomplish. Remember that all tags should be closed.

```
<select name= "Quad">
    <option value="1">Not important</option>
    <option value="3">Kind of important</option>
    <option value="6">Very Important</option>
    <option value="3">Only thing that matters</option>
</select>
```

For help finding these sorts of issues, run your page against an [html validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your `select` tags (using `</select>`) after the option lists:

```
<select name= "Gym">
    <option value="10">Arc</option>
    <option value="1">CRCE</option>
</select>
```

Do that to every list.